# Firebase SDK for Unity crashes app with Dynamic Link

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Has anyone tried the new Firebase SDK for Unity (https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)? When I tried to integrate Dynamic Link feature, it crashes the app when there is an invite.

I have created a brand new project with the minimum set up (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity) for Android to add Dynamic link to my project. When the app launches without an invite, it starts fine. But when the app launches through an invite (https://.app.goo.gl/?link=http://&apn=), it crashes with the following error:

```
11-15 09:46:00.929 16329-16329/com.my.app D/firebase: (InvitesClass) getInvitation:onResult:Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}
11-15 09:46:00.929 16329-16329/com.my.app D/Unity: (InvitesClass) getInvitation:onResult:Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}: 0 at ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp:42 (17408, 0, 0)
11-15 09:46:00.930 16329-16329/com.my.app I/Unity: (InvitesClass) getInvitation:onResult:Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}
 UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
 UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
 UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
 UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
 Firebase.FirebaseHandler:LogMessage(LogLevel, String)

 (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)



--------- beginning of crash

11-15 09:46:00.937 16329-16329/com.my.app A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 16329 (irg.app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is found to be a bug in the current version of the sdk(1.0.1):
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/11